# Entire database deletes instead of one row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to delete a row in my mySQL database on the onclick of a delete button. But instead of the one mySQL row getting deleted, all rows in the database get deleted.

I am targeting just the specific ID, so I am unclear as to why all other ID's are getting deleted.

HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($movies as $movie) : ?>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card card-cascade">
            <div class="view gradient-card-header purple-gradient">
                <h2><?php echo $movie['name']; ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $movie['genre']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body text-center">

                    <!-- Delete -->
                    <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-small btn-dribbble delbutton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" id="<?php echo $movie['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
  // Tooltips Initialization
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  // Delete Movie
  $(".delbutton").click(function() {
        console.log('watch me')
        var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this post? This cannot be undone later.")) {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "../movieApp/delete.php", //URL to the delete php script
                data : {id:info},
                success : function() {
                    console.log("success");
                    },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("failed");
                },
                });
            $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                opacity : "hide"
            }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
require 'config/config.php';
require 'config/db.php';

if($_POST['id']){
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $delete = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($delete);
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
echo "Worked!";
exit;
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record";
}
```

Comment: try adding single quote in `$id` like `$delete = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id='$id'";`

Comment: This does not do the trick sadly :(

Comment: have you tried the error function of ajax?

Comment: your code failed on more than one instance. Check for errors (and the console) and you'll see what you get back.

Comment: I did, no errors returned in the console.

Comment: note - need to include the connection in `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: @Sean I did, no errors.

Comment: You have `type : "POST"` but expect `$_GET['id']`?? And you are sending `id=' + del_id` but you are expecting `$_GET['info']`?

Comment: Lots of rooms to improve in your PHP script. You should at least return the results of your query to tell JS whether your delete action is made successfully or not. Also, there is no `$_GET['info']` defined in your JS. Do you mean `$_GET['id']` ? Last, it is a good practice NOT to delete things from DB; mark as delete by changing its status will be a better practice.

Comment: @Sean I updated the PHP to match the JS, still not working correctly.

Comment: @Raptor I see what you mean, just made those changes. See updated code. The AJAX logs success, yet it doesn't delete. For now, I need to delete the actual row permanently for this type of application btw

Comment: @Temple try `data : { id:info },` in your ajax..

Comment: @ShadowFiend I did, still nothing - ugh

Comment: @Temple That's not a good response should write. jQuery expects JSON response by default, you should: 1. format your response like Shadow Fiend suggest; and 2. add JSON header at the first line of PHP.

Comment: @Raptor, like I told ShadowFiend, I did. Still nothing. And I am confused as to what you mean adding the JSON header to PHP

Comment: @Temple can you please comment  out the `mysqli_escape_string` and instead of `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $delete) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` use `$conn->query($delete)`.

Comment: @ShadowFiend added all your changes, still not working.

Comment: @ShadowFiend updated the post field. It deletes now, problem is it delete all rows lol

Comment: Just add `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: No need, it deletes. About to update the question

Comment: @Temple try this again `data : {id:del_id}`.. Just remove the variable info.. and the single quote in the `'$id'`.. `id='$id'`; and try to look in the database if those things have the same `id's`, because that is maybe the reason why it deleted all..

Comment: @ShadowFiend Boom, thank you!!!!!! Seriously appreciate the help. Trying my best to learn mySQLi and this is my first application I am building. Thanks again.

Comment: @Temple welcome ^_^. I'm glad I was able to help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set ajax method `POST`, But Post data format is not correct as per your requirement.

> Change your `ajax` Data like as

```
 //var info = 'id=' + del_id;
 var info = {
   id : del_id
 }
```

> And

```
$.ajax({
  /*...*/
  data : info,
  /*.../
});
```

> And also check if your `id` field is string, If `integer` then change the Query string to -

```
#$delete = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id='$id'";
$delete = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=$id";
```

> Also change -

```
#$_POST['info']
$_POST['id']
```

Because, You didn't set `$_POST['info']` anywhere in your code.

**Note :** And don't forget to `console` your correct `Ajax URL`

Comment: This does not change anything.

Comment: I updated the answer, Check your `id` field, Make sure It is `string` or `Integer` @Temple

Comment: just fyi, from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - `data: It is converted to a query string, if not already a string`. So `var info = {id : del_id}` will end up being converted back to `id= '+ del_id`

Comment: Also change `$_POST['info']` to `$_POST['id']` because `$_POST['info']` is not set anywhere in your code. @Temple

Comment: This deletes all rows in the database instead of just the one instance.

Comment: All records were deleting due to an error on my part. Thanks for helping with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML use `data-id="<?php echo $movie['id']; ?>"` for the  tag. Then in your JS you can pick up the value like so: `var del_id = $(this).data("id");`. I would also inspect element in your browser to see if you are in fact sending an "id" to your PHP script. If you are then possibly you may want to enable error debugging in your PHP script like so: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Also wouldn't hurt to change your SQL statement to something like this: `$delete = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id='" . $id . "'";`. Good luck with this one doesn't sound too hard.

Comment: Had to take a second look at your question, you said ALL the rows are deleted? Which means your SQL statement works. I'm going to have to say all your rows have the same id then.